# init is not defined at onload

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Прошу помощи. 
Консоль стала ругаться на `<body onload="init ();">`.

Сайт, как я понимаю собран на laravel. 
Требовалось поменять контент. Внесли изменения в файл welcome.blade.php. И главная страница изменилась и всё поехало.
Изменения отменил, но ничего не изменилось и стала ругаться консоль.
В php и тем более laravel не разбираюсь. Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Консоль:

> (index):397 Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined
>       at onload ((index):397) onload @ (index):397

Comment: Ну, для начала, можно добавить проблемный код к вопросу.

Comment: на какой ответ вы рассчитываете?

Comment: А с какого файла добавить код? Как я понимаю стал грузиться другой шаблон. Сайт http://uzbekrf.ru

Comment: Что отвечает консоль добавил.

Comment: _Что отвечает консоль добавил_ ну и что это нам дает? Что за функция `init`, в каком файле она объявляется? Как этот файл загружается?

Comment: Сделайте поиск по проекту функции init, если найдете в каком она файле, то можете подключить его в welcome.blade.php